# CK editor disable width & height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I ran into an irritating feature of using [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

When you upload an image, in between your text content or wherever, ckeditor automatically fills in the width and height input fields as a default, which causes an html tag with `width` and `height` set in the `style` attribute:

```
<img alt="" src="/uploads/ckeditor/pictures/196/content_David_Leo006.jpg" style="width: 2000px; height: 669px;">
```

But if you delete the values in the input fields and then submit, the width and height is not set:

```
<img alt="" src="/uploads/ckeditor/pictures/196/content_David_Leo006.jpg">
```

Now like any normal, bright healthy web developer from the 21st century, I have a responsive design that takes care of these things, so I want the tags to always be generated like the latter. How can I hide and disable the input fields for width/height altogether?

CK editor's documentation is horribly chaotic

Answer (score 5):

I did something similar with Tables. I didn't want the end user putting in silly values as we were forcing responsive styling and width.

Maybe this code will help you:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev )
{
  var dialogName = ev.data.name;
  var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;


  if (dialogName == 'table') {

     // Get the advanced tab reference
     var infoTab2 = dialogDefinition.getContents('advanced');

     //Set the default

     // Remove the 'Advanced' tab completely
     dialogDefinition.removeContents('advanced');


     // Get the properties tab reference
     var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');

     // Remove unnecessary bits from this tab
     infoTab.remove('txtBorder');
     infoTab.remove('cmbAlign');
     infoTab.remove('txtWidth');
     infoTab.remove('txtHeight');
     infoTab.remove('txtCellSpace');
     infoTab.remove('txtCellPad');
     infoTab.remove('txtCaption');
     infoTab.remove('txtSummary');
  }
});
```

Comment: Where did you find the keywords ('txtBorder', 'cmbAlign', etc)?

Comment: @miqdadamirali I actually don't remember. I might have found them by checking source code, or I could have found it in documentation, or found it on another post or website. It was a long time ago now, and I don't work with CKEditor anymore so it could not even work for all I know.

Comment: @miqdadamirali As it happens I had to do this again recently. What you can do is a `console.log(infoTab);` on the above code which basically gives you an array that corresponds to all the HTML elements. So if you look at [this image](http://i.imgur.com/vz9A8K3.png) you'll see the ID's for the _Alternative Text_ and the _Vertical Spacing_ inputs on the image dialog. So to remove the latter you'd simply do `infoTab.remove('txtVSpace');`.

Comment: In my case `dialogName` is `tableProperties`, not `table`  (version 4+)

Comment: For completeness: `table` and `tableProperties` dialog names are referring to creating a new table vs. editing existing table properties respectively.

Answer (score 3):

CKEditor 4.5 now has a `image_prefillDimensions` config, which can be set to `false` to disable this auto-filling feature. See: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-image_prefillDimensions